# Proving that the ranks of two matrices are equal

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, matrix-rank, solution-verification

Given matrices such that $A^{2} = A$,  $B^{2} = B \,\ $and matrix $\,\ \mathbf{I} - (A + B)$ which is invertible. Prove that $rk(A) = rk(B)$.

What I tried to do is the following:

Let $C = \mathbf{I} - (A + B)$ $\implies$ $rk(CC^{-1})$ = rk($\mathbf{I}$) $\leq$ $rk(C)$ (*)

(*) Here I used the idea:  $rk(AB)$ $\leq$ $min(rk(A), rk(B))$

Since $rk(C)$ $\leq$ $rk(\mathbf{I}) - rk(A) - rk(B)$

Hence, $rk(\mathbf{I})$ $\leq$ $rk(\mathbf{I}) - rk(A) - rk(B)$ $\implies$ $rk(A)$$+rk(B)$ $\leq$ $0$

But since each rank is non-negative then the last inequality is true when each rank is zero.

I wonder if this is a valid proof because I have a slight doubt but everything seems legit, so please, if it is not give a hint.

If everything's ok do you see another way of proving? As I am a self-learner, it would be great if you share!

Comment: The "since $rk(C)$" line is not true.

Comment: why? aren't rk(A + B) <= rk(A) + rk(B)?

Comment: Yes, but then $rk(A-B) \le rk(A)+rk(-B) \ne rk(A) - rk(B)$

Comment: does rk(-B) =/= rk(B)?

Comment: Yes, but you implicitely used $rk(-B) = -rk(B)$, which is not true.

Comment: Ah, got it. Thx!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $0\ne v\in\operatorname{im}(A)$, we have $Av=v$ and thus $Cv=-Bv$. As $V$ is invertible, we conclude that $Bv\ne0$. So $\operatorname{im}(A)$ has trivial intersection with $\ker(B)$. Likewise,  $\operatorname{im}(B)$ has trivial intersection with $\ker(A)$. Conclude.

---

Alternative computation for the first step: Assume $v\in\operatorname{im}(A)\cap \ker(B)$. So $Bv=0$ and $v=Aw$ for some $w$.
Then
$$Cv=Iv-Av-Bv=Aw-A^2w-0=0. $$

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Could you please explain how did you deduce that Cv = Bv?

Comment: @Nik By dropping a sign ;)

Comment: "As $V$ is invertible", do you mean "$C$"?